# how to connect server using linux terminal?

Tags: command-line, likewise

I am currently using PuTTY to connect to my Linux server. However, I feel like it is unnecessary. Is there a way for me to connect to my Linux server directly from my terminal?

Comment: You want to learn how to use `ssh`. Try typing `man ssh` in a terminal, or search the internet for one of the many SSH tutorials available online.

Comment: If you want to connect from other machine, you have to install ssh on server and access it from a ssh client installed in second the machine. See [this article](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Configuring) for more detail.

Comment: Could you provide more detail on what you're trying to do?

Comment: Do you mean `cmd.exe` by _terminal_? I am assuming Windows as you mentioned PuTTY.

Answer (score 5):

If you have SSH installed on your server, you can connect very easily. Use the below command skeleton to sign-on through a terminal.

```
ssh username@remotehost.example.com
```

If you're using SSH keys, ensure that you have them in your `~/.ssh` folder. You may need to register them. Otherwise, the system will ask you for your password upon login.

To get more information about SSH and the command, type `man ssh` into your terminal.